# Womens' Yartzheits

Tags: women, yahrtzeit

There are plenty of resources that list yartzheits of famous tzaddikim. There have been plenty of famous women of note throughout the ages. Is there anywhere I can find a list of yartzheits of famous tzidkanios?

Comment: Wiki? (15 char)

Comment: There have been plenty more famous men, for better or worse. Are you sure your resources don't list women too and there just aren't that many?

Comment: I think lists of yartzeits usually have both. Do you want a list of just women?

Comment: I haven't found a yartzheir list that had more than like 5-10 women. There have been more than 10 righteous Jewish woman who have passed away. I don't mind if the list has men too as long as it has a large amount of women as well.